# How to Insert the contents of a rendered block into the body of a node?

Tags: 8, blocks

I need to place blocks inside body text (a youtube gallery plugin).

I’ve installed [Insert Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/insert_block)

I’ve successfully applied [patch #30](https://www.drupal.org/project/insert_block/issues/2648496#comment-12548879)

I was able to enable the module but the blocks don’t show up. I guess it is because the module is not actively maintained.

So it is not a good solution for now.

Since I’ve made my youtube playlist gallery based on youtube API, i can display my gallery with some html added to the body where i need to :

```
<p>lorem</p>
<div id="youtube_gallery_1" class="youtube_plugin"></div>
<p>lorem</p>
```

It works but it is not a very nice solution.

Is there an other way I can explore to do that ? I guess I need to create a custom filter in Drupal 8. Maybe there is an other approach or an other module ?

Comment: A custom filter is not another approach, it would be basically the same as one of the newer patches of this module. Another approach is the Media package, especially entity_embed, see this great blog post for an up-to-date tutorial https://www.webwash.net/managing-media-assets-using-core-media-in-drupal-8/

Comment: @4k4 You’re right. It is exactly the same approach. I’ve created a plugin which create a custom filter for Drupal 8 that replaces a pattern and adds the required html to the page. I’ll post my answer when it would be finished if no one answer before. Actually, it is working but I need to add the youtube playlist ID to the short code. I will study your blog post. Thanx !

Comment: @4k4 It is a great post. I have already done the "Embed Video Media Type" part and display a gallery with view. But I didn’t know it was possible to do that. The great part is that you can add a button into the editor. It is really nice for user experience. Please post it as an answer and i’ll up vote it.

Comment: @SébastienGicquel it may be easier to fix Insert Block and update the patch. Do you know what it there are errors during the installation or in the logs?

Comment: @awm I also try to debug this module. I think the issue is the `$block_id` is not found. The Array of all matches obtained with `preg_match_all` is correct but in the `foreach` the `$block_id` is null.

Comment: @awm There is a new patch (https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2018-06-08/2648496-46.patch) for insert_block and now the module works very well.